# Why is this value undefined in the scope of reduce but defined in a for loop? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, reduce

I'm trying to write a function to find the unique values in set of arrays...

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var result = [];

  for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++){
    console.log(args[i]);     // as expected this evaluates to [1, 3, 2]
                              // [5, 2, 1, 4]
                              // [2, 1]     

  }

  args.reduce(function(arg){
    console.log(arg + ' is the arg');  //for some reason arg is undefined
    arg.map(function(val){
      if (result.indexOf(val) < 0){
        result.push(val);

      }
      return result;
    });
  }, result);
}

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

Why is the above giving me `undefined` in the reduce but a valid value in the for loop?  Isn't the reduce function just implicitly looping over the values (i.e. producing `arg[0], arg[1],` etc?)

Edit: Here's the solution I got working...

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var result = [];

  args.reduce(function(acc, arg){
    console.log(arg + ' is the arg');  
    arg.map(function(val){
      if (result.indexOf(val) < 0){

        result.push(val);
        console.log(result + " is the current result");
      }
      return result;
    });
  }, result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You have `args` defined but not `arg`?

Comment: @TimothyG. `arg` is well defined as the argument of the callback of `reduce`.

Comment: This doen't look like the use case of `reduce`. It looks more of `forEach`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir not a big javascript user so I wouldn't know that.  It was just a sanity check.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir   But even if it's not the correct way to use reduce, isn't it still getting valid data types?  Why shouldn't the first instance of arg be defined as [1, 3, 2]?

Comment: The problem in your code is that you didn't return anything from the callback of `reduce` to be used as the new accumulator (`arg`).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  Ahh, I got it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can give you a good help. The callback function of the reduce should receive two arguments, the accumulator and the current value of the array you're iterating, so I believe it should look something like this:

```
function uniteUnique(arr) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var result = [];
    var helper;
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++){
        console.log(args[i]); 
    }

    args.reduce(function(acc, arg){
    console.log(arg + ' is the arg');
    helper = arg.map(function(val){
      if (result.indexOf(val) < 0){
        result.push(val);
      }
      return result;
    });
    return acc + helper;
  }, result);
}
```

Comment: This code won't work neither as you didn't adress the elephant in the code: **reduce should return something to be used as the first parameter to the callback (the accumulator for the next iteration)**!

Comment: @BrunoSantos   This looks right, but it looks like you forgot to define `acc`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you are totally right, i already fixed, gonna edit the answer

Comment: @DavidJ. the problem was that i was working the acc the wrong way. I already fixed the answer, but i see you gotta it working so, good work!